# Implementing a second battleship into a one dimensional game "River Battleship"

Tags: java

Would anybody be able to offer me a simple way to implement a second enemy battleship into a game I have designed to only have one enemy, this is my code currently :

```
import java.util.*; //Scanner that reads user input

public static void main(String[] arg) 
    {
        int riverLength = promptForInt("Select Length for River ") ; //Variable that stores the user input when prompted
        int [] shipArray = new int[riverLength] ; //User input is used to create an Array, i.e. River Size
        int battleshipCoordinates = new Random().nextInt(riverLength) ; //Random number is found within the Array (Where the enemy ship will hide) 

        shipArray[battleshipCoordinates] = 1 ; 
        boolean hit = false ; //Statement created for ship hit and default to false
        int playerSelection; //int Variable declared

        do
       {
           displayRiver (shipArray, false);
           playerSelection = promptForInt(String.format("Select location to launch torpedo (1 - %d) ", riverLength));
           playerSelection = playerSelection -1 ; 

           if(shipArray[playerSelection] == 1 ) //if a user strikes the Enemy (Case 1) correctly they system informs them of a strike
           {
            System.out.println("Battleship Sunk!");
            hit = true; 
            displayRiver(shipArray, true);
           }
           else if(shipArray[playerSelection] == -1)
           {
            System.out.println("Location already Hit! Try again.");
           }
           else if(shipArray[playerSelection] == 0)
           {
            System.out.println("Miss!");
            shipArray[playerSelection] = -1 ; 
           }

       } while(!hit); 




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 0 - Create a new battleship and place them on the array just like the first one.

Step 1- Change your boolean hit to an int equaling 2.

Step 2- Instead of toggling hit, reduce it by 1 when you hit a ship and then set 
that position on the array to a 0.

Step 3- Adjust your logic so that you do not win unless hit < 1